# Can't install any operating system due to glitches

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, kali-linux

I was trying to install kali Linux on my pc through a bootable USB. Everything started normally but when the installation started suddenly a colorful glitch appeared on my screen and my PC became unresponsive. It happened with me every time I tried to install Linux.

Finally, I also tried to install Windows but this time the setup didn't even start the glitch appeared again.

I also have windows 7 bootable cd. Though it is corrupted I thought to give it a shot, everything went well. I couldn't install it because the cd was corrupted but the glitch didn't appear this time.

When I had Linux installed on my PC, it happened with me 5 to10 minutes after booting that's why I tried to reinstall Kali.

The glitch was similar to this image. Just the color changed a few. https://www.google.com/search?q=glitch+monitor&client=ms-android-vivo&prmd=isnv&sxsrf=ACYBGNRmuajLjsOP4PgZ94mKUaWYL148gQ:1574736169117&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwirmuav7YbmAhXy4jgGHSy-D8AQ_AUoAXoECBAQAQ&biw=360&bih=562&dpr=1.5#imgrc=wGM17VfXoQMCWM%3A

Comment: It looks like a defective graphics card.

Comment: I thought that too but I am thinking that why it doesn't happen on startup. It always happens after some time and the pc also becomes unresponsive.

Comment: It happens under load. Quite typical.

Comment: Any way to resolve it? I have not seen this problem when booting through cd and it has intel integrated graphics,  so it means that I have to change my cpu.

Comment: Replace it and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try it and inform you if it works.

Comment: I tried re-installing my CPU the problem was not solved but my CPU was too hot when the glitch occured. Is it a possible problem?

Comment: @Xavier2001.7.3, no, the Intel on-board gfx chipsets are not attached to the CPU. It's attached/soldered to the motherboard. Unfortunately for most laptops with Intel graphics it means replacing the motherboard.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I have a desktop with integrated graphics that's why I should change my CPU. Right ?